# can't execute javascript onclick event from html which is being outputted by php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm stumped...i'm trying to execute a latitude and longitude search within a php block but when pressing the button to execute the javascript, it only executes when outside of the php...is there a work around?

my code...

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])): ?>
    <P class="lead">You are not authorized to view this page.</P>
        <?php else: ?>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="latitude">Latitude</label>
                        <input type="text" name="latitude" class="form-control" id="latitude" value="<?php echo $latitude;?>">
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="longitude">Longitude:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="longitude" class="form-control" id="longitude" value="<?php echo $longitude;?>">
                </div>

                <button onclick="getLocation()">Use Current Latitude & Longitude</button> 
                //this button does not execute here but it will execute if placed AFTER the <?php endif ?> found below...This is killing me...I'm thinking the function and button onclick event aren't communicating because of it's placement within the php code but is there a work around?...i tried escaping the quotes and double quotes to single and vice versa and replacing the blocks of code in different areas but couldn't get it to work
                </div>

            </form></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var lat = document.getElementById("latitude");
                var long = document.getElementById("longitude");

                function getLocation() {
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                    } else {
                        lat.value = "Geolocation is not supported .";
                        lat.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                    }
                }

                function showPosition(position) {
                    lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
                    long.value = position.coords.longitude;
                }
            </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

//like i stated above...if i place that button here after this php endif it will work

Comment: What do you mean by "it only executes when outside of the php"?

Comment: You do realise that javascript run only in the browser and PHP runs only in the server dont you? So you cannot run javascript `inline` so to speak within a piece of PHP

Comment: Are you expecting the javascript to execute server side?  If that were possible, it would return your servers geolocation, not your users.

Comment: you need pass the value from (lat and long) to your function (getLocation)...:function getLocation(lat, long){.....}

Comment: and the same for showPosition function

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to initialize the Php session using session_start(). See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php. Before the if statement you should call session_start();

Comment: The session is started...I didn’t put all the code in but I have a header with the session included

Comment: You have a closing div tag after the closing form tag. It seems to be out of place